# Serial fir filter in VHDL

Tags: filter, vhdl

I want to do a serial fir filter with LUT table. Here is my code:

Register module

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity reg is 
port(
    clk, rst : in std_logic;
    d           : in std_logic_vector(13 downto 0);
    q           : out std_logic_vector(13 downto 0)
);
end reg;

architecture arch of reg is

signal q_reg, q_next : std_logic_vector(13 downto 0);

begin
    process(clk, rst)
        begin
        if (rst ='1') then
                q_reg <= (others => '0');
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            q_reg <= q_next;
        end if;
    end process;

    q_next <= d;
    q <= q_reg;

end arch;
```

Adder module:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity add is
port (
    a,b : in std_logic_vector(13 downto 0);
    s    : out std_logic_vector(13 downto 0)
);
end add;

architecture arch of add is

signal result : signed(13 downto 0);
begin
    result <= signed(a) + signed(b);
    s        <= std_logic_vector(result);
end arch;
```

Lut table:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;


entity lut_table is
port(
    table_in  : in std_logic_vector(8 downto 0);
    table_out : out std_logic_vector(13 downto 0)
);
end lut_table;

architecture arch of lut_table is
begin

    with table_in select
        table_out <= "00000000000000"       when    "000000000",
"00000001101110"        when    "000000001",
"11111110111011"        when    "000000010",
"00000000101001"        when    "000000011",
"00000101000000"        when    "000000100",
"00000110101110"        when    "000000101",
"00000011111011"        when    "000000110",
"00000101101001"        when    "000000111",
"00010001000101"        when    "000001000",
"00010010110011"        when    "000001001",
"00010000000000"        when    "000001010",
"00010001101110"        when    "000001011",
"00010110000101"        when    "000001100",
"00010111110011"        when    "000001101",
"00010101000000"        when    "000001110",
"00010110101110"        when    "000001111",
"00100110100110"        when    "000010000",
"00101000010100"        when    "000010001",
"00100101100001"        when    "000010010",
"00100111001111"        when    "000010011",
"00101011100110"        when    "000010100",
"00101101010100"        when    "000010101",
"00101010100001"        when    "000010110",
"00101100001111"        when    "000010111",
"00110111101011"        when    "000011000",
"00111001011001"        when    "000011001",
"00110110100110"        when    "000011010",
"00111000010100"        when    "000011011",
"00111100101011"        when    "000011100",
"00111110011001"        when    "000011101",
"00111011100110"        when    "000011110",
"00111101010100"        when    "000011111",
"00010001000101"        when    "000100000",
"00010010110011"        when    "000100001",
"00010000000000"        when    "000100010",
"00010001101110"        when    "000100011",
"00010110000101"        when    "000100100",
"00010111110011"        when    "000100101",
"00010101000000"        when    "000100110",
"00010110101110"        when    "000100111",
"00100010001010"        when    "000101000",
"00100011111000"        when    "000101001",
"00100001000101"        when    "000101010",
"00100010110011"        when    "000101011",
"00100111001010"        when    "000101100",
"00101000111000"        when    "000101101",
"00100110000101"        when    "000101110",
"00100111110011"        when    "000101111",
"00110111101011"        when    "000110000",
"00111001011001"        when    "000110001",
"00110110100110"        when    "000110010",
"00111000010100"        when    "000110011",
"00111100101011"        when    "000110100",
"00111110011001"        when    "000110101",
"00111011100110"        when    "000110110",
"00111101010100"        when    "000110111",
"01001000110000"        when    "000111000",
"01001010011110"        when    "000111001",
"01000111101011"        when    "000111010",
"01001001011001"        when    "000111011",
"01001101110000"        when    "000111100",
"01001111011110"        when    "000111101",
"01001100101011"        when    "000111110",
"01001110011001"        when    "000111111",
"00000101000000"        when    "001000000",
"00000110101110"        when    "001000001",
"00000011111011"        when    "001000010",
"00000101101001"        when    "001000011",
"00001010000000"        when    "001000100",
"00001011101110"        when    "001000101",
"00001000111011"        when    "001000110",
"00001010101001"        when    "001000111",
"00010110000101"        when    "001001000",
"00010111110011"        when    "001001001",
"00010101000000"        when    "001001010",
"00010110101110"        when    "001001011",
"00011011000101"        when    "001001100",
"00011100110011"        when    "001001101",
"00011010000000"        when    "001001110",
"00011011101110"        when    "001001111",
"00101011100110"        when    "001010000",
"00101101010100"        when    "001010001",
"00101010100001"        when    "001010010",
"00101100001111"        when    "001010011",
"00110000100110"        when    "001010100",
"00110010010100"        when    "001010101",
"00101111100001"        when    "001010110",
"00110001001111"        when    "001010111",
"00111100101011"        when    "001011000",
"00111110011001"        when    "001011001",
"00111011100110"        when    "001011010",
"00111101010100"        when    "001011011",
"01000001101011"        when    "001011100",
"01000011011001"        when    "001011101",
"01000000100110"        when    "001011110",
"01000010010100"        when    "001011111",
"00010110000101"        when    "001100000",
"00010111110011"        when    "001100001",
"00010101000000"        when    "001100010",
"00010110101110"        when    "001100011",
"00011011000101"        when    "001100100",
"00011100110011"        when    "001100101",
"00011010000000"        when    "001100110",
"00011011101110"        when    "001100111",
"00100111001010"        when    "001101000",
"00101000111000"        when    "001101001",
"00100110000101"        when    "001101010",
"00100111110011"        when    "001101011",
"00101100001010"        when    "001101100",
"00101101111000"        when    "001101101",
"00101011000101"        when    "001101110",
"00101100110011"        when    "001101111",
"00111100101011"        when    "001110000",
"00111110011001"        when    "001110001",
"00111011100110"        when    "001110010",
"00111101010100"        when    "001110011",
"01000001101011"        when    "001110100",
"01000011011001"        when    "001110101",
"01000000100110"        when    "001110110",
"01000010010100"        when    "001110111",
"01001101110000"        when    "001111000",
"01001111011110"        when    "001111001",
"01001100101011"        when    "001111010",
"01001110011001"        when    "001111011",
"01010010110000"        when    "001111100",
"01010100011110"        when    "001111101",
"01010001101011"        when    "001111110",
"01010011011001"        when    "001111111",
"11111110111011"        when    "010000000",
"00000000101001"        when    "010000001",
"11111101110110"        when    "010000010",
"11111111100100"        when    "010000011",
"00000011111011"        when    "010000100",
"00000101101001"        when    "010000101",
"00000010110110"        when    "010000110",
"00000100100100"        when    "010000111",
"00010000000000"        when    "010001000",
"00010001101110"        when    "010001001",
"00001110111011"        when    "010001010",
"00010000101001"        when    "010001011",
"00010101000000"        when    "010001100",
"00010110101110"        when    "010001101",
"00010011111011"        when    "010001110",
"00010101101001"        when    "010001111",
"00100101100001"        when    "010010000",
"00100111001111"        when    "010010001",
"00100100011100"        when    "010010010",
"00100110001010"        when    "010010011",
"00101010100001"        when    "010010100",
"00101100001111"        when    "010010101",
"00101001011100"        when    "010010110",
"00101011001010"        when    "010010111",
"00110110100110"        when    "010011000",
"00111000010100"        when    "010011001",
"00110101100001"        when    "010011010",
"00110111001111"        when    "010011011",
"00111011100110"        when    "010011100",
"00111101010100"        when    "010011101",
"00111010100001"        when    "010011110",
"00111100001111"        when    "010011111",
"00010000000000"        when    "010100000",
"00010001101110"        when    "010100001",
"00001110111011"        when    "010100010",
"00010000101001"        when    "010100011",
"00010101000000"        when    "010100100",
"00010110101110"        when    "010100101",
"00010011111011"        when    "010100110",
"00010101101001"        when    "010100111",
"00100001000101"        when    "010101000",
"00100010110011"        when    "010101001",
"00100000000000"        when    "010101010",
"00100001101110"        when    "010101011",
"00100110000101"        when    "010101100",
"00100111110011"        when    "010101101",
"00100101000000"        when    "010101110",
"00100110101110"        when    "010101111",
"00110110100110"        when    "010110000",
"00111000010100"        when    "010110001",
"00110101100001"        when    "010110010",
"00110111001111"        when    "010110011",
"00111011100110"        when    "010110100",
"00111101010100"        when    "010110101",
"00111010100001"        when    "010110110",
"00111100001111"        when    "010110111",
"01000111101011"        when    "010111000",
"01001001011001"        when    "010111001",
"01000110100110"        when    "010111010",
"01001000010100"        when    "010111011",
"01001100101011"        when    "010111100",
"01001110011001"        when    "010111101",
"01001011100110"        when    "010111110",
"01001101010100"        when    "010111111",
"00000011111011"        when    "011000000",
"00000101101001"        when    "011000001",
"00000010110110"        when    "011000010",
"00000100100100"        when    "011000011",
"00001000111011"        when    "011000100",
"00001010101001"        when    "011000101",
"00000111110110"        when    "011000110",
"00001001100100"        when    "011000111",
"00010101000000"        when    "011001000",
"00010110101110"        when    "011001001",
"00010011111011"        when    "011001010",
"00010101101001"        when    "011001011",
"00011010000000"        when    "011001100",
"00011011101110"        when    "011001101",
"00011000111011"        when    "011001110",
"00011010101001"        when    "011001111",
"00101010100001"        when    "011010000",
"00101100001111"        when    "011010001",
"00101001011100"        when    "011010010",
"00101011001010"        when    "011010011",
"00101111100001"        when    "011010100",
"00110001001111"        when    "011010101",
"00101110011100"        when    "011010110",
"00110000001010"        when    "011010111",
"00111011100110"        when    "011011000",
"00111101010100"        when    "011011001",
"00111010100001"        when    "011011010",
"00111100001111"        when    "011011011",
"01000000100110"        when    "011011100",
"01000010010100"        when    "011011101",
"00111111100001"        when    "011011110",
"01000001001111"        when    "011011111",
"00010101000000"        when    "011100000",
"00010110101110"        when    "011100001",
"00010011111011"        when    "011100010",
"00010101101001"        when    "011100011",
"00011010000000"        when    "011100100",
"00011011101110"        when    "011100101",
"00011000111011"        when    "011100110",
"00011010101001"        when    "011100111",
"00100110000101"        when    "011101000",
"00100111110011"        when    "011101001",
"00100101000000"        when    "011101010",
"00100110101110"        when    "011101011",
"00101011000101"        when    "011101100",
"00101100110011"        when    "011101101",
"00101010000000"        when    "011101110",
"00101011101110"        when    "011101111",
"00111011100110"        when    "011110000",
"00111101010100"        when    "011110001",
"00111010100001"        when    "011110010",
"00111100001111"        when    "011110011",
"01000000100110"        when    "011110100",
"01000010010100"        when    "011110101",
"00111111100001"        when    "011110110",
"01000001001111"        when    "011110111",
"01001100101011"        when    "011111000",
"01001110011001"        when    "011111001",
"01001011100110"        when    "011111010",
"01001101010100"        when    "011111011",
"01010001101011"        when    "011111100",
"01010011011001"        when    "011111101",
"01010000100110"        when    "011111110",
"01010010010100"        when    "011111111",
"00000001101110"        when    "100000000",
"00000011011100"        when    "100000001",
"00000000101001"        when    "100000010",
"00000010010111"        when    "100000011",
"00000110101110"        when    "100000100",
"00001000011100"        when    "100000101",
"00000101101001"        when    "100000110",
"00000111010111"        when    "100000111",
"00010010110011"        when    "100001000",
"00010100100001"        when    "100001001",
"00010001101110"        when    "100001010",
"00010011011100"        when    "100001011",
"00010111110011"        when    "100001100",
"00011001100001"        when    "100001101",
"00010110101110"        when    "100001110",
"00011000011100"        when    "100001111",
"00101000010100"        when    "100010000",
"00101010000010"        when    "100010001",
"00100111001111"        when    "100010010",
"00101000111101"        when    "100010011",
"00101101010100"        when    "100010100",
"00101111000010"        when    "100010101",
"00101100001111"        when    "100010110",
"00101101111101"        when    "100010111",
"00111001011001"        when    "100011000",
"00111011000111"        when    "100011001",
"00111000010100"        when    "100011010",
"00111010000010"        when    "100011011",
"00111110011001"        when    "100011100",
"01000000000111"        when    "100011101",
"00111101010100"        when    "100011110",
"00111111000010"        when    "100011111",
"00010010110011"        when    "100100000",
"00010100100001"        when    "100100001",
"00010001101110"        when    "100100010",
"00010011011100"        when    "100100011",
"00010111110011"        when    "100100100",
"00011001100001"        when    "100100101",
"00010110101110"        when    "100100110",
"00011000011100"        when    "100100111",
"00100011111000"        when    "100101000",
"00100101100110"        when    "100101001",
"00100010110011"        when    "100101010",
"00100100100001"        when    "100101011",
"00101000111000"        when    "100101100",
"00101010100110"        when    "100101101",
"00100111110011"        when    "100101110",
"00101001100001"        when    "100101111",
"00111001011001"        when    "100110000",
"00111011000111"        when    "100110001",
"00111000010100"        when    "100110010",
"00111010000010"        when    "100110011",
"00111110011001"        when    "100110100",
"01000000000111"        when    "100110101",
"00111101010100"        when    "100110110",
"00111111000010"        when    "100110111",
"01001010011110"        when    "100111000",
"01001100001100"        when    "100111001",
"01001001011001"        when    "100111010",
"01001011000111"        when    "100111011",
"01001111011110"        when    "100111100",
"01010001001100"        when    "100111101",
"01001110011001"        when    "100111110",
"01010000000111"        when    "100111111",
"00000110101110"        when    "101000000",
"00001000011100"        when    "101000001",
"00000101101001"        when    "101000010",
"00000111010111"        when    "101000011",
"00001011101110"        when    "101000100",
"00001101011100"        when    "101000101",
"00001010101001"        when    "101000110",
"00001100010111"        when    "101000111",
"00010111110011"        when    "101001000",
"00011001100001"        when    "101001001",
"00010110101110"        when    "101001010",
"00011000011100"        when    "101001011",
"00011100110011"        when    "101001100",
"00011110100001"        when    "101001101",
"00011011101110"        when    "101001110",
"00011101011100"        when    "101001111",
"00101101010100"        when    "101010000",
"00101111000010"        when    "101010001",
"00101100001111"        when    "101010010",
"00101101111101"        when    "101010011",
"00110010010100"        when    "101010100",
"00110100000010"        when    "101010101",
"00110001001111"        when    "101010110",
"00110010111101"        when    "101010111",
"00111110011001"        when    "101011000",
"01000000000111"        when    "101011001",
"00111101010100"        when    "101011010",
"00111111000010"        when    "101011011",
"01000011011001"        when    "101011100",
"01000101000111"        when    "101011101",
"01000010010100"        when    "101011110",
"01000100000010"        when    "101011111",
"00010111110011"        when    "101100000",
"00011001100001"        when    "101100001",
"00010110101110"        when    "101100010",
"00011000011100"        when    "101100011",
"00011100110011"        when    "101100100",
"00011110100001"        when    "101100101",
"00011011101110"        when    "101100110",
"00011101011100"        when    "101100111",
"00101000111000"        when    "101101000",
"00101010100110"        when    "101101001",
"00100111110011"        when    "101101010",
"00101001100001"        when    "101101011",
"00101101111000"        when    "101101100",
"00101111100110"        when    "101101101",
"00101100110011"        when    "101101110",
"00101110100001"        when    "101101111",
"00111110011001"        when    "101110000",
"01000000000111"        when    "101110001",
"00111101010100"        when    "101110010",
"00111111000010"        when    "101110011",
"01000011011001"        when    "101110100",
"01000101000111"        when    "101110101",
"01000010010100"        when    "101110110",
"01000100000010"        when    "101110111",
"01001111011110"        when    "101111000",
"01010001001100"        when    "101111001",
"01001110011001"        when    "101111010",
"01010000000111"        when    "101111011",
"01010100011110"        when    "101111100",
"01010110001100"        when    "101111101",
"01010011011001"        when    "101111110",
"01010101000111"        when    "101111111",
"00000000101001"        when    "110000000",
"00000010010111"        when    "110000001",
"11111111100100"        when    "110000010",
"00000001010010"        when    "110000011",
"00000101101001"        when    "110000100",
"00000111010111"        when    "110000101",
"00000100100100"        when    "110000110",
"00000110010010"        when    "110000111",
"00010001101110"        when    "110001000",
"00010011011100"        when    "110001001",
"00010000101001"        when    "110001010",
"00010010010111"        when    "110001011",
"00010110101110"        when    "110001100",
"00011000011100"        when    "110001101",
"00010101101001"        when    "110001110",
"00010111010111"        when    "110001111",
"00100111001111"        when    "110010000",
"00101000111101"        when    "110010001",
"00100110001010"        when    "110010010",
"00100111111000"        when    "110010011",
"00101100001111"        when    "110010100",
"00101101111101"        when    "110010101",
"00101011001010"        when    "110010110",
"00101100111000"        when    "110010111",
"00111000010100"        when    "110011000",
"00111010000010"        when    "110011001",
"00110111001111"        when    "110011010",
"00111000111101"        when    "110011011",
"00111101010100"        when    "110011100",
"00111111000010"        when    "110011101",
"00111100001111"        when    "110011110",
"00111101111101"        when    "110011111",
"00010001101110"        when    "110100000",
"00010011011100"        when    "110100001",
"00010000101001"        when    "110100010",
"00010010010111"        when    "110100011",
"00010110101110"        when    "110100100",
"00011000011100"        when    "110100101",
"00010101101001"        when    "110100110",
"00010111010111"        when    "110100111",
"00100010110011"        when    "110101000",
"00100100100001"        when    "110101001",
"00100001101110"        when    "110101010",
"00100011011100"        when    "110101011",
"00100111110011"        when    "110101100",
"00101001100001"        when    "110101101",
"00100110101110"        when    "110101110",
"00101000011100"        when    "110101111",
"00111000010100"        when    "110110000",
"00111010000010"        when    "110110001",
"00110111001111"        when    "110110010",
"00111000111101"        when    "110110011",
"00111101010100"        when    "110110100",
"00111111000010"        when    "110110101",
"00111100001111"        when    "110110110",
"00111101111101"        when    "110110111",
"01001001011001"        when    "110111000",
"01001011000111"        when    "110111001",
"01001000010100"        when    "110111010",
"01001010000010"        when    "110111011",
"01001110011001"        when    "110111100",
"01010000000111"        when    "110111101",
"01001101010100"        when    "110111110",
"01001111000010"        when    "110111111",
"00000101101001"        when    "111000000",
"00000111010111"        when    "111000001",
"00000100100100"        when    "111000010",
"00000110010010"        when    "111000011",
"00001010101001"        when    "111000100",
"00001100010111"        when    "111000101",
"00001001100100"        when    "111000110",
"00001011010010"        when    "111000111",
"00010110101110"        when    "111001000",
"00011000011100"        when    "111001001",
"00010101101001"        when    "111001010",
"00010111010111"        when    "111001011",
"00011011101110"        when    "111001100",
"00011101011100"        when    "111001101",
"00011010101001"        when    "111001110",
"00011100010111"        when    "111001111",
"00101100001111"        when    "111010000",
"00101101111101"        when    "111010001",
"00101011001010"        when    "111010010",
"00101100111000"        when    "111010011",
"00110001001111"        when    "111010100",
"00110010111101"        when    "111010101",
"00110000001010"        when    "111010110",
"00110001111000"        when    "111010111",
"00111101010100"        when    "111011000",
"00111111000010"        when    "111011001",
"00111100001111"        when    "111011010",
"00111101111101"        when    "111011011",
"01000010010100"        when    "111011100",
"01000100000010"        when    "111011101",
"01000001001111"        when    "111011110",
"01000010111101"        when    "111011111",
"00010110101110"        when    "111100000",
"00011000011100"        when    "111100001",
"00010101101001"        when    "111100010",
"00010111010111"        when    "111100011",
"00011011101110"        when    "111100100",
"00011101011100"        when    "111100101",
"00011010101001"        when    "111100110",
"00011100010111"        when    "111100111",
"00100111110011"        when    "111101000",
"00101001100001"        when    "111101001",
"00100110101110"        when    "111101010",
"00101000011100"        when    "111101011",
"00101100110011"        when    "111101100",
"00101110100001"        when    "111101101",
"00101011101110"        when    "111101110",
"00101101011100"        when    "111101111",
"00111101010100"        when    "111110000",
"00111111000010"        when    "111110001",
"00111100001111"        when    "111110010",
"00111101111101"        when    "111110011",
"01000010010100"        when    "111110100",
"01000100000010"        when    "111110101",
"01000001001111"        when    "111110110",
"01000010111101"        when    "111110111",
"01001110011001"        when    "111111000",
"01010000000111"        when    "111111001",
"01001101010100"        when    "111111010",
"01001111000010"        when    "111111011",
"01010011011001"        when    "111111100",
"01010101000111"        when    "111111101",
"01010010010100"        when    "111111110",
"01010100000010"        when    "111111111";
end arch;
```

Top level entity file:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity top is
port(
    clk, rst : in std_logic;
    data_in : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    data_out : out std_logic_vector(13 downto 0);
    aaa     : out unsigned(3 downto 0);
    ena : out std_logic;
    data_p : out std_logic_vector(8 downto 0)
);
end top;


architecture arch of top is

signal tablein : std_logic_vector(8 downto 0);
signal tableout: std_logic_vector(13 downto 0);
signal addout,add1,add2  : std_logic_vector(13 downto 0);
signal reg_in, reg_out : std_logic_vector(13 downto 0);
--signal tap0, tap1, tap2, tap3, tap4, tap5, tap6, tap7 : std_logic_vector(8 DOWNTO 0);
signal x0, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8 : std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0);
--signal y0, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6, y7,y8 : std_logic_vector(13 downto 0);
--type TYPEX is array (8 downto 1) of std_logic_vector(8 downto 0);
type TYPET is array (0 to 7) of std_logic_vector(8 downto 0);
signal tap : TYPET;
--signal x : TYPEX;
signal i : unsigned(3 downto 0);
signal enaa : std_logic;

component reg
port(
    clk, rst : in std_logic;
    d           : in std_logic_vector(13 downto 0);
    q           : out std_logic_vector(13 downto 0)
);
end component;



component add
port(
    a,b : in std_logic_vector(13 downto 0);
    s    : out std_logic_vector(13 downto 0)
);
end component;

component lut_table
port(
    table_in  : in std_logic_vector(8 downto 0);
    table_out : out std_logic_vector(13 downto 0)
);
end component;

begin

a2: add port map (
    a => add1,
    b => add2,
    s => addout
);

a3: reg port map (
    clk => clk,
    rst => rst,
    d => reg_in,
    q => reg_out
);


lut: lut_table port map(
    table_in => tablein,
    table_out => tableout
 );


add1 <= tableout;
add2 <= reg_out;
reg_in <= addout;

x0 <= data_in;
process(clk, enaa)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) and enaa = '1' then
        x0 <= data_in;
        x2 <= x1; 
        x3 <= x2; 
        x4 <= x3;
        x5 <= x4; 
        x6 <= x5; 
        x7 <= x6; 
        x8 <= x7;  
        end if;
end process;
    tap(0) <= (x8(0) & x7(0) & x6(0) & x5(0) & x4(0) & x3(0) & x2(0) & x1(0) & x0(0));
    tap(1) <= (x8(1) & x7(1) & x6(1) & x5(1) & x4(1) & x3(1) & x2(1) & x1(1) & x0(1));
    tap(2) <= (x8(2) & x7(2) & x6(2) & x5(2) & x4(2) & x3(2) & x2(2) & x1(2) & x0(2));
    tap(3) <= (x8(3) & x7(3) & x6(3) & x5(3) & x4(3) & x3(3) & x2(3) & x1(3) & x0(3));
    tap(4) <= (x8(4) & x7(4) & x6(4) & x5(4) & x4(4) & x3(4) & x2(4) & x1(4) & x0(4));
    tap(5) <= (x8(5) & x7(5) & x6(5) & x5(5) & x4(5) & x3(5) & x2(5) & x1(5) & x0(5));
    tap(6) <= (x8(6) & x7(6) & x6(6) & x5(6) & x4(6) & x3(6) & x2(6) & x1(6) & x0(6));
    tap(7) <= (x8(7) & x7(7) & x6(7) & x5(7) & x4(7) & x3(7) & x1(7) & x1(7) & x0(7));

        x0 <= data_in;
process(clk)
begin
    if rst = '1' then
        i <= "0000";
     elsif rising_edge(clk) and i = "0001" then
        enaa <= '1';
        tablein <= tap(to_integer(i));
        data_p <= tap(to_integer(i));
        aaa <= i;    
        i <= i + "0001";
        ena <= '1';
        aaa <= i;
    elsif rising_edge(clk) and i < "1000" then
        i <= i + "0001";
        enaa <= '0';
        ena <= '0';
        aaa <= i;
    elsif rising_edge(clk) and i = "1000" then
        enaa <= '0';
        i <= "0001";
        ena <= '0';
        aaa <= i;
    end if;
end process;    



with enaa select
        data_out    <= reg_out when '1',
                        "00000000000000" when '0';

end arch;
```

I have big problems with top level file because I don't know how to put enter samples to lut table and create an fsm. Anyone helps ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your Look Up Table, it will be easier to handle if you create it as Read Only Memory block.

Something like this:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity lut_table is
port(
    table_in  : in std_logic_vector(8 downto 0);
    table_out : out std_logic_vector(13 downto 0)
);
end lut_table;


Architecture ROM of lut_table is
    -- Build a 2-D array type for the ROM
    type rom_type is array (0 to 511) of std_logic_vector (13 downto 0); 
    constant rom_mem : rom_type := ("00000000000000",
        "00000001101110",
        "11111110111011",
            ...
        "01010100000010"
    );

begin

    data_output <= rom_mem(conv_integer(address_in));

end ROM;
```

This way you can change its content fast.